# Python Error using Clip Tool: 000732: Dataset does not exist or is not supported

Tags: arcpy, clip, error-000732

I'm getting `Error 000732 Dataset does not exist or is not supported`.

I have tried formatting my files names as "\", r (explicit text) and forward slashes and none seem to work.  (I've also verified that the datasets do indeed exist).

Here's the code:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Set enviornment
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\\ARCGIS\\DIR1\\DIR2\\Master.gdb"

# Script arguments
ThingToBeClipped = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Local variables:
Clipper = r"D:\ARCGIS\DIR1\DIR2\Another_GDB.gdb\Clipper"
OutputClipped = r"D:\ARCGIS\DIR1\DIR2\Master.gdb\Output"

# Process: Clip
arcpy.Clip_analysis("ThingToBeClipped", "Clipper", "Output", "")
```

Comment: What kind of device is the D: drive? local harddrive, CD/DVD, network share, etc.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: What is `ThingToBeClipped`?  Are you sure the error is referring to your output and not this input?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your entire error message, not just a part of it.  Include line numbers that relate to the code snippet you've provided.

Comment: Where are you executing the code? As a script within modelbuilder, in the Python window etc.?